# Vue - redirect after MSAL loginRedirect

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

How do I implement the following authentication flow in Vue.js using MSAL `loginRedirect()`?

```
SourcePage > isLoggedIn() = false > /login > MSAL.loginRedirect() > handleResponse() > SourcePage
```

We were previously using MSAL `loginPopup()` in the above flow by including the `SourcePage` url as a route param string and redirecting after the login was confirmed.

However because `loginRedirect()` navigates away from the page to authenticate, before returning to `handlePromise()` we have lost the original route param strings

`redirectStartPage()` looks like it should do what I want but appears to redirect *before* it gets to `handleResponse()`

Answer (score -1):

For authentication methods with redirect flows (loginRedirect and acquireTokenRedirect), you will need to explicitly register a callback through the handleRedirectCallback() method. This is needed since redirect flows do not return promises as the popup methods do.

Learn more about the redirect flow [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-core/docs/FAQ.md#i-dont-understand-the-redirect-flow-how-does-the-handleredirectcallback-function-work)